# HTML Improvements Duplicate title tags in images

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content

For my website Google Webmaster Tool is showing more than 700 duplicate title tags. All are images url. I am in a trouble, because I have uploaded all images to wp-content/uploads. But in WMT the link of images are indexed as url of the post added with alt text of the image as attribute. I don't know from where they are coming from, as I have uploaded them on wp-content/uploads. What should I do to get rid of. Anyone who helps me will be appreciated. This website is on WordPress.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are reading this message wrongly. What it is telling you is that multiple pages on your site have duplicate TITLE tags (the ones in your HEAD). Since they are duplicates, it means that you haven't provided anything to distinguish one from the other. This means that users searching Google will see nearly identical results for both pages. WMT is suggesting that you page something different to distinguish them. It seems like what is happeing is that you are using the same title for multiple pages. Maybe you can just add ' - Page 1', ' - Page 2', etc to each of those pages.

UPDATE: OK, it appears that all of your images have been uploaded twice. You want to delete all of the images which end in '*-2'. After you've done that most of those duplicates should disappear. You may need to remove them from the Media Manager in WP to make them fully disappear. If you've linked to any of these duplicates then you'll need to update your links in your blog as well. I hope this is something that can easily be taken care of manually.

Comment: thanks for response mr. krowe. I have not repeated same title in any page. These links access image pages but not post. As you can see    http://www.howto-connect.com/how-to-add-administrative-tools-to-the-windows-8-start-screen/windows-8-start-screen-settings-screen-2/    as well as  http://www.howto-connect.com/how-to-add-administrative-tools-to-the-windows-8-start-screen/windows-8-start-screen-settings-screen/. All the links are accessed in image pages.

Comment: I am unable to understand from where these links came. as i have uploaded all my images in wp-content/uploads

Comment: The content may be images but they are being delivered as part of a full webpage. This is an image: http://www.howto-connect.com/wp-content/uploads/windows-8-start-screen-settings-screen1.png and this is a webpage: http://www.howto-connect.com/how-to-add-administrative-tools-to-the-windows-8-start-screen/windows-8-start-screen-settings-screen-2/ . There is a big difference.

Comment: but I have uploads only images. From where these urls are coming out, I am totally confused.

Comment: Actually these links are coming from media library. each media file has created a link as shown above. But what could be the solution. please. can anyone suggest me for solution?

Comment: See my update for the solution to get rid  most of your duplicate titles.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a "feature" where it creates a page for every image you upload.  This page is useless and WordPress really shouldn't be doing that.

Luckily plugins can fix the problem.  For example Yoast has the ability to redirect the image page URLs to the image itself.  See https://kb.yoast.com/kb/redirect-image-attachment-urls/

If you use a plugin to get rid of the page for each image, you won't have this duplicate title problem anymore.