# Google Webmaster Tools is showing duplicate URLs based on page title differences

Tags: google-search-console, url, google-search, canonical-url, title

I have 700+ title tag duplicates showing in WMT.

[image]

Every first link in that picture is as duplicate link of second one. I don't know from where the first link got indexed by Google when that link doesn't exist in the site. It's showing the title of every page as link.

Original link: `http://www.sitename.com/job/407/Swedish-plus-Any-other-Nordic-Language-Customer-Service-Representative-Dublin-Ireland`.

Duplicate link: `http://www.sitename.com/job/407/Swedish-plus-Any-other-Nordic-Language-Customer-Service-Representative-Dublin-Ireland-Ireland`.

How can this happen? I have checked entire site I didn't find where the second version is linked.

I have no images linked to with duplicated version of URL.

Comment: @Satya that question didn't resolved the problem and it's not at all related to image.

Comment: I agree that http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53033/html-improvements-duplicate-title-tags-in-images?lq=1 is not a duplicate.  That problem is caused by duplicate posts, this one is a canonicalization issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, you need to implement [URL Canonicalization](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)

> Many sites make the same HTML content or files available via different URLs. Say you have a clothing site and one of your top items is a green dress. The product page for the dress may be accessible through several different URLs

Use 301 redirects, or canonical meta tags as suggested in that article to solve the problem.

Comment: but how can i know form where those duplicate links got generated in WMT. If i know where is that url got linked from i can maintain unique url structure site wide.

Comment: At this point it doesn't matter where Google found the link.  Even if you remove that link, Googlebot will continue crawling both versions forever and the report in webmaster tools will likely never go away.

Comment: So you mean adding <link rel="canonical" href="link for original vesion"> in the page will solve this issue?

Comment: Correct.  Adding that canonical meta tag will let Googlebot know that the pages are the same page, and not separate pages with the same title.

Comment: In this case the canonical tag will be in both the versions of the page. will this affect original version page. Thank you..

Comment: [Google's Maile Ohye says](http://moz.com/blog/dispelling-a-persistent-rel-canonical-myth): ...it's absolutely okay to have a self-referential rel="canonical". It won't harm the system and additionally, by including a self-reference you better ensure that your mirrors have a rel=”canonical” to you.

Comment: If I have identified your site correctly, some of these duplicate pages with 'Ireland' on the end are linking from your 'Jobs with Dropbox 'page. You can use a web crawler such as Screaming Frog, or Xenu to help you find where pages are linked from.

Comment: @moobot Your comment really helped me a lot!! Thank you so much.